# React routing - react-router-dom pushState() call to history happens too many times

Tags: react-redux, safari, react-router-dom, browser-history

I am using react-router-dom (v6) and noticed that I cannot use the browsers back button as expected. It seems like my application (using react/redux) pushes the location multiple times to the browser history when I am routing to a different location in my app.

This results in an application crash in Safari too:

> SecurityError: Attempt to use history.pushState() more than 100 times per 30 seconds

The code looks something like this:

**App.tsx**

```jsx
...
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route path={ROUTES.auth.login} element={<PublicRoute component={Login} />} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.auth.register} element={<PublicRoute component={Register} />} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.dashboard} element={<PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} />} />
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
...
```

**PublicRoute.tsx**

```jsx
...
export default function PublicRoute({ propsForComponent = {}, ...props }: PublicRouteProps): ReactElement {
    const { showLoadingScreen } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
        showLoadingScreen: state.loading.showLoadingScreen,
    }));

    const { component: Component } = props;

    if (showLoadingScreen) return <LoadingOverlay />;

    return <Component {...propsForComponent} />;
}
...
```

I found out that the *PublicRoute* component gets called multiple times due to the connection to the redux store with the useSelector hook.

*showLoadingScreen* gets updated when the application is trying to fetch the user, during this time this variable changes.

So my question is now: how do I prevent multiple re-renders, which causes the **history.pushState()** calls?

I know I could move the *LoadingOverlay* component to a different entry point. But In *PrivateRoute* I am also connected to the redux state because I need to access the user object. (I used the *PublicRoute* component to show a minimal example of whats going on...)

Any help would be highly appreciated,
cheers!